# Keyword constructor in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I'm a "beginner" in typescript.Right now I'm stuck at constructors.Can anyone define what is a constructor for me along with an example in strings (possibly an easy to understand example)?
p.s. I don't have any code to show its a theory question
Thanks

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html

Comment: Sorry ,but i din't  find constructor in the official documentation.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript is JavaScript plus a static typing system, early adoption of some proposed features that haven't been formally adopted into JavaScript yet, and a couple of features that almost certainly won't ever be adopted into JavaScript. So let's start with the JavaScript part of this.

A *constructor function* (often just "constructor") is a functon used with the `new` keyword to create an object with a specific prototype. For instance, `Example` in this statement is a constructor function:

```
const ex = new Example();
```

The `new Example()` part of that does two things:

1. Creates a new object that inherits from the object that the `Example.prototype` property refers to.
2. Runs the code in `Example` with `this` referring to the newly-created object

In modern JavaScript (and in TypeScript), you create a constructor function via `class` syntax

```
class Person {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Prior to ES2015 you used traditional function syntax, but now that `class` syntax is available, if you use constructor functions (as opposed to any of the other coding paradigms that JavaScript and TypeScript also support, such as functional programming), you use `class` syntax as it's more concise for non-trivial examples and has several features the traditional function syntax doesn't.

A `class` constructor function can *only* be called as a constructor, it can't be called except as part of creating a new instance.

Here's a simple example:

```
class Person {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    sayHi() {
        console.log(`Hi, I'm ${this.name}`);
    }
}
```

Using it:

```
const p = new Person("FlyingBird");
p.sayHi(); // "Hi, I'm FlyingBird"
```

Moving to TypeScript, the only really TypeScript-specific features of constructors per se is that you can use syntax in their parameter list to create properties automatically. In the JavaScript example above, the constructor had the parameter `name` which it used to create a public property called `name` on the object being created. In TypeScript, you can do the same thing somewhat more concisely:

```
// TypeScript
class Person {
    constructor(public name: string) {
    }
    sayHi() {
        console.log(`Hi, I'm ${this.name}`);
    }
}
```

The `public` on the `name` parameter tells TypeScript to automatically assign that parameter's value to a public property with the same name. You can also use `private` to assign to a TypeScript-style private property. (TypeScript's private properties aren't really private, though they're usually good enough; they's different from JavaScript's own *private fields* [which aren't properties].)